# Rebasing dependent topic branches

Tags: git, rebase

I use a lot of local topic branches in git, and sometimes end up with dependencies between topic branches causing rebase problems. For example, with a structure like:

```
master ---> featureA ---> featureB
                     \--> featureC
```

If `master` changes and I get (and resolve) conflicts when rebasing `featureA`, then afterwards rebasing `featureB` onto `featureA` triggers the same conflicts (and sometimes exciting new ones as well) because it tries to reapply the patches from the `featureA` branch. Assuming that the actual patches between `featureA` and `featureB` would apply cleanly if cherry-picked, is there a way of doing a rebase in this situation with roughly the same effect as cherry-picking all of the commits between `featureA` and `featureB`?

Comment: See also [how I'd rebase a whole subhistory -- several branches, with some links between them resulting from merge](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9706495/94687). The unpleasant part of that solution is the need to reset the topic branch refs to the new rebased commits afterwards.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After rebasing `featureA`, you can do

```
git rebase --onto featureA oldFeatureA featureB
```

assuming `oldFeatureA` represents the commit at the tip of `featureA` before you rebased it (you can either keep another branch there or just remember the commit hash).

This should basically be the same as cherry-picking each commit between A and B onto the rebased version of A.

[Documentation on git-rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) (includes some helpful pictorial explanations of what happens during some more complex rebase operations)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'd figured out that --onto looked like it should do the job, but using the old tip as a base didn't occur to me.

Comment: Instead of `oldFeatureA`, it should be possible to use `featureA@{1}`, assuming that the rebase was the last change to that branche. Otherwise use something like `@{2}`, `@{3}`, or `@{one hour ago}`

Answer (score 6):

For the future, if you work with lot of interdependent topic branches, perhaps you should consider using [TopGit](http://repo.or.cz/w/topgit.git) ([README](http://repo.or.cz/w/topgit.git?a=blob;f=README)), a tool to manage patch queue using Git topic branches, one patch per branch; or alternatively a tool to manage multiple topic branches.

See e.g. [topgit Means Never Having to Wait for Reviews](http://blog.grogmaster.com/2008/12/topgit-means-never-having-to-wait-for.html) blog posts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at TopGit! TopGit seems to aim at the right thing: maintaining interdependent branches. **But does TopGit has the feature to rebase my interdependent topic branches onto a new upstream state?** If it could, I could use TopGit to develop and prepare my patches as branches for a review and possible pulling by the upstream.

Comment: See also [Some discussion about a "rebase-based TopGit"](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Branch-dependencies-td6641429.html): " I think a new 'system' needs to be 'rebase' based, not merge based like TopGit"

Answer (score 1):

```
git rebase -–update-refs
```

(after [Git 2.38](https://github.blog/2022-10-03-highlights-from-git-2-38/#rebase-dependent-branches-with-update-refs))