# Git - rebasing a set of branches

Tags: git, rebase

If I have a set of branches with common ancestor commit `a`, is there an easy way to rebase all of them onto commit `b` (where the common ancestor of `a` and `b` might be some third commit `c`)?

Comment: Are you trying to rebase the commits since `a` on each branch, or the commits since `c` on each branch?

Comment: See also [how I'd rebase a whole subhistory -- several branches, with some links between them resulting from merge](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9706495/94687). The unpleasant part of that solution is the need to reset the topic branch refs to the new rebased commits afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Just rebase them all.

If you anticipate repeated conflicts, enable git-rerere, which records your conflict resolutions and is able to automatically apply the same resolution when merge encounters the exact same conflicts in another (re)merge.

- see http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html

Or you could,

1. Isolate commit `a` in a branch

   ```
    git checkout -b temporary <commita>
   ```
2. Rebase the `temporary` branch onto commit `b`.
3. Rebase all the 'related' branches onto the resulting branch `temporary`